# Is it possible to get type of the column?

Tags: tabulator

[Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/components#component-column) detects type of the column by analyzing data in first row.

I want to apply my custom editor based on detected type to a column after [table is built](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/callbacks#table)

Is it possible to access detected column's type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im afraid that isn't possible, There is no column type as such, tabulator simply attempts to guess the correct sorter to be used on a column if one hasn't been defined in the column definition.

Comment: I can see that Tabulator tests column type in some places. It would be nice if that info will be accessible. This is useful while extending Tabulator